# conflicting htaccess for subfolder wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, conflict

I have a website www.domain.com with a subfolder www.domain.com/subsite/domain/ and in the subfolder there's a wordpress installation.

currently the primary site works as it should and I'm able to view the wordpress index page and the admin area but every time I try to access one of the front-side inner pages I get a 404 error.

the primary htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^wordpress/(.*)$  - [R=403,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wordpress
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [r=301,nc]
```

And the wordpress installation htaccess:

```
# WPhtc: End Custom htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your primary htaccess file as this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^subsite/domain(/|$) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{http_host}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**UPDATE:**

And this should be your `/subsite/domain/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subsite/domain/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't have any effect

Comment: For which URL are you getting 404?

Comment: domain.com/wordpress/anything, but not for domain/wordpress/wp-admin/anything

Comment: Still not working. I can't see how this will be relevant (which is why I didn't add it in the first place) but "wordpress" is actually "subsite/domain/" (ie the wordpress root is www.domain.com/subsite/domain/)

Comment: Your comment is confusing. Is wordpress in a separate subdomain? You never mentioned about `/subsite/domain/` before.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect this. basically when I wrote /wordpress/ I summarized /subsite/domain/ since I didn't think it'll have any influence on the answer

Comment: What is full URL to your Wordpress blog? Is it in a subdomain?

Comment: if the current site's url is www.domain.com then the wordpress blog url is www.domain.com/subsite/domain/
ie www.google.com and www.google.com/subsite/google/

Comment: See updated code and replace `/subsite/domain/` with your actual path.

Comment: still getting the 404 page

Comment: For which URL you're getting 404?

Comment: as before - in any inner page of the wordpress installation (www.google.com/subsite/google/somepage)

Comment: Actually I had a typo in my first rule, try again. If you still get 404 then rename this root .htaccess and see if 404 goes away.

Comment: I still got the error even after renaming the outer htaccess so maybe it's something else messed up in the settings.
Anyway for future reference your answer did solve the problem when I recreated it on another server.

Comment: Great to know it worked out. I had spent a lot of time on your answer :)